# How to display thumbnails and title in combined PHP/HTML?

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails

I'd like to display titles and thumbnails of my posts using this code snippet, which I'm unable to do so.

How do I solve this problem?

#### Code

```
<div class="row">
    <?php     
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full');
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');?>    
    </div>    
    echo '<h5 class=" card-title "><a href=" '.get_permalink() .' ">'.get_the_title().'</a></h5 >';?>
    <p class="card-text "><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="btn btn-primary"> Continue Reading &raquo;
                </a>
            </div>
            <?php  
    endwhile;
    else :
        _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.', 'textdomain' );
    endif;?>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to use an editor that has a syntax highlighter, at least when coding. The reason may be those "early closing symbols" and PHP code outside its own tag. This things can be seen quite easy when having a code editor with syntax highlighter. [Syntax highlighted code](https://i.imgur.com/DSF9Tv1.png)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you might have PHP codes in your HTML. Maybe, try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php 
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full'); ?> 
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
                </div>
                <?php  echo '<h5 class=" card-title "><a href=" ' . get_permalink() .' ">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h5 >'; ?>
                <p class="card-text"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-primary"> Continue Reading &raquo;</a>
            </div>
            <?php  endwhile;
            else :
                _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.', 'textdomain' );
        endif; 
    ?>
</div>
```

- If it did not solve your problem, maybe look into your syntax errors/warnings.
- You might consider indenting your codes, it would help you find errors without looking into error logs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried using the code provided but it is not showing the image, whereas what you said might be correct. Syntax error. I have edited the code a bit, now it's showing the images but showing syntax error in the code editor. Can you please check the code once and share your advice  Sorry I am was unable to post the new code. Thank you for your help today.